# Fitbit API issues using PHP

Tags: php, api, fitbit

Brand new to the Fitbit API but this is what I've got so far.

- I've successfully installed OAuth on my server and verified.
- I downloaded Fitbit's PHP example - completeAuthorization.php however
  after browsing to it on my server and clicking "Allow" it takes me to
  localexample.fitbit.com/php/completeAuthorization.php?oauth_token=...&oauth_verifier=...
  which is a 404. oauth_token and oauth_verifier removed to protect the
  innocent
- I drop that idea and then try to use the GitHub project FitbitPHP and
  created (based on their README.md file) the following:

  ```
  require 'fitbitphp.php';

  $fitbit = new FitBitPHP(FITBIT_KEY, FITBIT_SECRET);

  $fitbit->setUser('XXXXXX');
  $xml = $fitbit->getProfile();

  print_r($xml);
  ```

The XXXXXX is my 6 digit user ID I pulled from my profile. The screen is rendering a blank white page and I'm not sure how to diagnose this. I used the API Explorer and seemed to have positive results. Could someone provide some much needed direction? My goal is to simply output my profile data so I can style it on a webpage. Thanks in advance.

Sources:

[FitbitPHP on GitHub](https://github.com/heyitspavel/fitbitphp)

[Fitbit API docs using PHP](https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/API+PHP+Client)

Comment: Possibly need to turn on error messages?

Comment: Turned it on but not getting any output. I will check logs.

Comment: Checked the logged and was seeing that FITBIT_KEY & FITBIT_SECRET were not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FITBIT_KEY & FITBIT_SECRET were not previously defined in the GitHub provided wrapper. This has to be defined in order to pull data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code - it's working fine for me.

```
require 'fitbitphp.php';

$consumer_key ='fe31e0c7da0340a1b407dc8013adaf161223343';
$consumer_secret='4dcd125021094d45bc405ab0343q2231984f432';

$fitbit = new FitBitPHP($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);


$fitbit->setUser('XXXXXX');
$xml = $fitbit->getProfile();

print_r($xml);
```